# What is the difference on a Wamp or Web Server for the definition of $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] and where does it get defined on both?

Tags: live, wamp

What is the difference on a Wamp or Web Server for the definition of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and where does it get defined on both?

And the reason I ask is I have a bunch of live websites that use the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` definition.

On the live websites, `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` works perfectly.

On wamp server locally, it shows `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` as **C:/wamp/www** even though I have virtual hosts set up. Everything on wamp works except for the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` declaration.

I used a php script suggested as a fix. The prepend_script set in auto_prepend_file in php.ini:is as follows:

```
auto_prepend_file = c:/wamp/www/prepend_script.php

$basePath = dirname(__FILE__); // assuming this script is in c:/wamp/www
$projectPath = preg_replace('#('.$basePath.'/[^/]+)/.*#i', '\\1', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = $projectPath;
```

What that did was change the`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` from **C:/wamp/www** to **/itsaboutwirelessnetworks/index.php**

When in actuality for it to function properly it should be **C:/wamp/www/itsaboutwirelessnetworks** and not **/itsaboutwirelessnetworks/index.php** as the prepend script did.

So in order for myself and others to understand how this can affect them, I would appreciate an explanation of why it works on my live server and not the wamp server.

Hence the original question:

What is the difference on a Wamp or Live Web Server for the definition of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'`] and where does it get defined on both?

Comment: I've added some basic formatting to try and make it a bit more readable. Please try and use the formatting buttons or markdown code in the future to help us understand what's going on

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) says about DOCUMENT_ROOT: (emph mine)

> The document root directory under
>   which the current script is executing,
>   **as defined in the server's
>   configuration file.**

So you should look at your config file and check if there is something strange there i'd say.

(I think that unless you've changed it,  **C:/wamp/www** sounds like a valid value to assign to your document-root. If it should be something else, that must be defined in the config of the virtual host)

Comment: Its has been defined in the virtual host. I have the following in the vhost.conf:  '<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
   DocumentRoot C:\wamp\www\itsaboutwirelessnetworks
   ServerName itsaboutwirelessnetworks.localhost
   ServerAlias itsaboutwirelessnetworks
</VirtualHost>' and it still points to the docroot of the wamp installation and not the virtual host. Since this has been reported as a bug as far back as 2003, I imagine there must be a fix somewhere. The script in the OP somewhat works but why is it appending the /index.php. If I know the answer to that question, then I have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug in Apache, as it's defined in the Apache httpd.conf file.

http://www.devcha.com/2010/02/solved-incorrect-value-for.html

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=26052

Apache/php/mysql websites are most often run on Linux servers and you're developing on Windows, the large differences between them could well account for the different bug behaviour.